# Select all buttons except one with jQuery -2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I have this code :

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav" id="filters">
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn active" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
```

I would like select all buttons from div #filters except the only one with #sort, using jQuery's selector.

Currently I have tried to achieve this by following code.

```
$('#filters').not('#sort').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
     var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
     $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button:not("#sort")', function() {
         $buttonGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
         $( this ).addClass('active');
     });
});
```

Can you help me ?

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `.not('#sort')` rest it should work https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/fvkmn2bu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`.not()`** in your selector and find buttons as **`$('#filters > button')`** by using **[Child Selector (“parent > child”)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**

Your question and code is bit confusing but It says that you want to apply the `active` class on button when it clicked and removed from other buttons.

The following click event will work on `all the buttons except #sort`.

```
$('#filters > button').not($('#sort')).click(function(){
  $('#filters > button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```js
$('#filters > button').not($('#sort')).click(function(){
  $('#filters > button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
 background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav" id="filters">
                        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn active" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#filters *").not("#sort")` selector.

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$("#filters button").on("click",function(){
  $("#filters *").not("#sort").removeClass('active');
  $(this).not("#sort").addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav navbar-nav" id="filters">
  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn active" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a css :not selector like this:

```
$("#filters button:not('#sort')")
```